# Question not linked to my account

Tags: support, questions, user-accounts, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

[This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785267/sharp-sign-in-query-string-and-seo) was probably one of my first on SO and it looks like it's not linked to my [account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217288/yojimbo87). Question has the same gravatar picture but account is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged your accounts... *with my mind.*

Comment: k, now your gravitar is freaking me out.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: http://i.imgur.com/q8ZF2.jpg

Comment: ot, but fyi, the link in your profile here on meta is broken... feel free to delete this message  ;-)